# R maps package displaying county as wildcard pattern

Tags: r, package, maps

R maps package displaying county as wildcard pattern.
Ex. While trying to draw - `map("county", region=c("texas,gray"))`
the map fetches counties - "grey" and "greyson", whereas the expectation is to draw only gray county.
Any fixes/workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see `?maps::map`

> exact
>   If TRUE, only exact matches with regions are selected for
>   drawing. If FALSE, each element of regions is matched as a regular
>   expression against the polygon names in the database and all matches
>   are selected for drawing.

```
map("county", region=c("texas,gray"), exact=TRUE)
```